# Redirect from Facebook Pinterest app/canvas page

Tags: facebook, canvas

I set up a Pinterest canvas page on my Facebook account, and when I click on the boards, it doesn't redirect to Pinterest - it's just a blank page.

1. Is there a way to set it to redirect to Pinterest if I click on a board? Here is the link: http://www.facebook.com/elainegriffindesigns/app_278747155534522
2. The funny thing is in IE9 when I click on a board, I get this message:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame. What you can try: Open this content in a new window (which is a link)

If I can't set the app to redirect, can I set it to have the option of opening in a new window? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest has shut down that functionality but you can add you Pinterest profile to your Facebook page using Woobox's app instead.

http://woobox.com/pinterest